# Fitting a paragraph inside a kivy label

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

So I've got a label inside a .kv file that has a paragraph set as the text. Now the text is of course broken up on different lines within the file held together by doc-strings so it doesn't run forever to the right. When I set the label text equal to the paragraph its alignment is way off. Everywhere I've pressed enter within the text, to drop it down to prevent the over-running, also shows up in the label. Is there a way to ignore those so the text is viewed as if it were on a single line?

```
Label:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "top"
    halign: "left"
    text: """This is an example paragraph used to show how the text is broken
    up inside the code. I lack the knowledge on how to remove the breaks from
    pressing the 'ENTER' key. I am once again asking for your help"""
```

Idk if this is common either but everywhere I have a comma, the single space after it is ignored and I am required to double space for a single space to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the `ENTER` with a `\` as below:

```
        text:
            """This is an example paragraph used to show how the text is broken\
 up inside the code. I lack the knowledge on how to remove the breaks from\
 pressing the 'ENTER' key. I am once again asking for your help"""
```

Note that the triple quote starts on a new line and is indented. The `\` escapes the carriage returns at the end of the lines. And each additional line starts with a space (only because it is a space between words).

You can also do this using string concatenation:

```
    text:
        'This is an example paragraph used to show how the text is broken' +\
        ' up inside the code. I lack the knowledge on how to remove the breaks from' +\
        ' pressing the "ENTER" key. I am once again asking for your help'
```

The above uses the `+` operator, but again the  newlines must be escaped, otherwise the kivy lang parser will interpret the newline as the end of the element.

Comment: Yes, that is what is used in my answer.

Comment: @usr2564301, I don't think that will work since the kivy lang parser will not recognize that the string after the newline is part of the same element. If you can come up with a working example, please post it. I don't claim to know every possibility.